# Pandas reshape a dataframe with each row a cell value with column name and index

Tags: python, pandas

Assume I have a data frame which can be represented by:

```
pd.DataFrame(columns=['X', 'Y'],index=['A','B'])

    X   Y
A   1   2
B   3   4
```

Then I would like to apply function to each cell to get a dataframe with each row a cell value with column name and index like:

```
   Col1  Col2  Value
1   X     A     1
2   Y     A     2
3   X     B     3
4   Y     B     4
```

I know I can loop it to get the result, but I hope a better Pandas like approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and for convert `MultiIndex` to columns [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html), for new columns names add [`Series.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rename_axis.html) and change order of columns by subset:

```
df = df.stack().rename_axis(('Col2','Col1')).reset_index(name='Value')[['Col1','Col2','Value']]
print (df)
  Col1 Col2  Value
0    X    A      1
1    Y    A      2
2    X    B      3
3    Y    B      4
```